# Dart return Future<dynamic> previously casted as different Type from a function

Tags: dart

I need to return some type as `Future<dynamic>`. I have attached a simplified version of my code. I always get the Error "**A value of type 'String' can't be returned from function 'testFunc' because it has a return type of 'Future'**"

Even if i do "dynamic returnVal = text" and return that, i got an exception "**Unhandled exception:
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Future< dynamic>'**"

```
import 'dart:async';

void main(List<String> args) async {
  dynamic gotVal = await testFunc();

  print(gotVal);
}

Future<dynamic> testFunc() {
  String text = "Bla";
  return text;
}
```

I was able to fix it with a Completer, but for me that seems wrong. Is it really the only solution to use a Completer like this? :

```
import 'dart:async';

void main(List<String> args) async {
  dynamic gotVal = await testFunc();

  print(gotVal);
}

Future<dynamic> testFunc() {
  String text = "Bla";

  Completer completer = Completer();
  completer.complete(text);

  return completer.future;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rewrite your testFunc adding **async** keyword to its definition:

```dart
Future<dynamic> testFunc() async {
  String text = "Bla";
  return text;
}
```

Comment: That was just too simple, did not noticed it. Thank you! Now i know for what the async is for :)